# Django _meta many to many

Tags: python, django

I am writing a shell utility that allows me to traverse relations so that I don't need to go back to my models and see how tables are related. I am using `_meta` in order to get all this information.

Look at the following sample models:

```
class Foo:
    ...

class Bar:
    foo = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

and this is what happens when I use `_meta` to find the m2m fields:

```
In [33]: Bar._meta.many_to_many
Out [33]: [<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: foos>]
In [34]: Foo._meta.many_to_many
Out [34]: []
```

is there something that will return `[<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: bars>]` by asking for the m2m relations with the `Foo` model?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. The following will return a list of `RelatedObject`'s for a model, that is the reverse of a many-to-many field.

```
related_objects = Foo._meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()
```

The field can be accessed with `related_object.field`. Note that this is still a field *from*  `Bar` *to* `Foo`, it is the exact same field as returned by `Bar._meta.many_to_many`.

To get all many-to-many fields pointing to or from a model, you can do this:

```
many_to_many = (Foo._meta.many_to_many 
           + [r.field for r in Foo._meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()])
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. `get_all_related_many_to_many_objects` gets m2m relations in fk relations. if you look above, this will not work for my current example.

Comment: @RyanSaxe What doesn't work exactly? In my current project it works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below to fetch all the related relations (reverse) of a Django model. Using `related_objects` which will return an iterable with all the relation definitions to the model. The iterable represents all the relations (`one-to-one`, `one-to-many`, `many-to-one`, `many-to-many`).

```
from django.db.models.fields.reverse_related import ManyToManyRel
from apps import models as app_models


def get_relations(obj):
    main_model = obj._meta.model

    counter = 0
    for x in main_model._meta.related_objects:
        counter += 1

        relation = ''
        if x.one_to_one:
            relation = 'one-to-one'
        elif x.one_to_many:
            relation = 'one-to-many'
        elif x.many_to_one:
            relation = 'many-to-one'
        elif x.many_to_many:
            relation = 'many-to-many'

        model = x.related_model

        print "{}) Relation: {} {} {}".format(
            counter, str(main_model._meta), relation, str(model._meta)
        )
        if isinstance(x, ManyToManyRel):
            field_name = x.field.m2m_reverse_field_name()
            query_set = x.through.objects.filter(**{field_name: obj})
        else:
            field_name = x.field.name
            query_set = model.objects.filter(**{field_name: obj})
        print "Count: {}".format(query_set.count())
        print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"


obj = app_models.ModelName.objects.get(id=123)
get_relations(obj)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I only partially tested your approach, so take this with a grain of salt, but for some reason my many_to_many-relation: `<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: top_investors>` shows up as `<ManyToOneRel: landmatrix.dealtopinvestors>` in your approach. Maybe it needs to be with a `through` to turn into a "real" many_to_many. i dont know.